# jjanzic/docker-python3-opencv installing python 3.9 instead of 3.7

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, opencv, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to deploy my old docker into a new AWS server and found TensorFlow and other libraries are not installing.

My docker file is `FROM jjanzic/docker-python3-opencv`

After checking this command `docker run -it jjanzic/docker-python3-opencv python` found the python version is 3.9 instead of 3.7

The docker is working fine on my other server.

[image: Screenshot of the python version]

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are using [latest](https://hub.docker.com/r/jjanzic/docker-python3-opencv/dockerfile) version of the image which is in python 3.9.

If you want python 3.7 you have to use older version:

```
docker run --rm -it jjanzic/docker-python3-opencv:opencv-4.0.1 python
```